# can't echo to or cat from a device file that was created by mknod

Tags: c++, c, device-driver

I created a character device file in the `/dev/` folder like this:

`mode_t mode = S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH|S_IFCHR;`

`const char * pathname = "/dev/tty.myown;"`

`int res = mknod(pathname, mode, 0);`

It successfully created the character device file. So I called `cat` on it by calling `cat /dev/tty.myown` and then tried sending a message to it by running: `echo "hello world" > /dev/tty.own`. However the message was not displayed in the `cat` stream. I was wondering what other settings i need to set on that file in order to be able to read from that device file

Comment: Why would you expect reading from a terminal device to return what was written to it? When you write to a terminal device, it prints it on the screen. When you read from a device, it returns what the user typed on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX standard (.1-2001) states:

> The only portable use of mknod() is to create a FIFO-special file.  If mode is not S_IFIFO or dev is not 0, the behavior of mknod() is unspecified

You are attempting to create a character-special file (i.e. not S_IFIFO). In particular, on Linux, device number 0 is [a null device](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt) which ought to do absolutely nothing. If you want a FIFO, set `S_IFIFO` instead of `S_IFCHR`.

Comment: ahh thanks for the info. Do you know if those number mean the same thing on Mac OS X?

Comment: @mjl007 I believe that you should still be using S_IFIFO,0 on Mac OS X, and I *guess* that 0 still means null/no-op device when used with `S_IFCHR`, but I'm not sure on the latter.